# JavaScript create span element inside div

Tags: javascript, html

The following is the HTML that does what I want. It displays `category:` and beneath a value that I send in JavaScript.

```
<div id="category-order-id" class="additional-order-info">
   <!-- <span class="additional-order-info-grey">category:</span>
      Clothes -->
</div>
```

And here is my JavaScript

```
let orderCategory = document.getElementById("category-order-id");
orderCategory.textContent = `${order.category}`;
let categorySpan = document.createElement("span");
categorySpan.setAttribute("class", "additional-order-info-grey");
categorySpan.textContent = "category:";
orderCategory.appendChild(categorySpan);
```

What this code does, it that it first displays `Clothes` value that I send with JavaScript and beneath it display `category`.

Why I am creating a `span` element here is because if I set `textContent` of `orderCategory` it wil not display the `span` at all.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

textContent property replaces all the content in the element. If you want to keep order.category and "category:" as content, you need to use the appendChild function:

```
let orderCategory = document.getElementById("category-order-id");
const catTextContent = document.createElement("span");
catTextContent.textContent = order.category;
let categorySpan = document.createElement("span");
categorySpan.setAttribute("class", "additional-order-info-grey");
categorySpan.textContent = "category:";
orderCategory.appendChild(catTextContent);
orderCategory.appendChild(categorySpan);
```